# I can't delete worlds

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Minecraft on my Kindle Fire, but it won't let me delete certain worlds. I go to edit, click on the x next to the world, but it still stays there! Is there a different way to delete worlds? Or is it a glitch?

Comment: I play on my kindle and it works fine. In fact, it works so fine I accidentally deleted my favorite world, and it took me months to finish my hotel!

Answer (score 1):

For my Nexus 7 Android, I could plug the device to my computer, browse to `This PC\Nexus 7\Sisäinen tallennustila\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds` and delete a folder called `My World`, which was the *name of the world*. Apologies for localized folder name.